# When DMA usage is actually needed?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, dma

I know a bit of DMA, but cannot understand when I should use it, let's say, instead of usual allocation mechanisms like `kmalloc` with specific flags. Also I'm aware of `ZONE_DMA` which usage means that hardware can map only to that zone, but in linux kernel I can see that somewhere it uses `dma_*` specific functions and `kmalloc` respectively, so my questions:

Only some specific hardware can use DMA? It cannot use usual memory allocation mechanisms? When I should use `dma_*` specific functions and `kmalloc` with `GFP_DMA`?

Comment: **A)** When you need to unload CPU from some job (slow buses, like SPI or UART), or **B)** when CPU, especially in multi-tasking OSes, simply is too slow to serve the traffic. DMA can be device specific (most of them) and GP (General Purpose). They may or may not (the latter is the main case) support m2m (memory-2-memory) transfers. Note, using DMA **adds** latency to the flow.

Comment: ZONE_DMA32 is used to support 32-bit hardware DMA on systems with more than 4G  ZONE_DMA is even older.You will probably never need it. https://lwn.net/Articles/753273/

Comment: @0andriy, can you give an example where in the kernel this is used and possible to use ordinary allocation mechanisms instead, please?

Comment: Everywhere. There are plenty of drivers for all possible cases. Do your homework. You may start from _drivers/dma/_ in the Linux kernel source tree along with reading and understanding DMA related documentation.